# Yii cgrid table join for showing an image

Tags: php, yii

I'm pretty new on Yii and i have some problems... I have 2 tables **events** and **events_images** , I'm trynig to list all the *events* (name, descripton, date and so on...) and also to show one small thumbnail image from the **events_images** table. I know how to list all the infos from the events table but i don't konw how to make the join to show one picture from the events_images.

---

The tables are looking like this:

**Events-**
ID
type
title
description
date

**Events_images-**
ID
event_id
path

Tanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "`with()`" is the function [you are looking for](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/10185-using-relations-and-conditions/) if you have the relations defined.

Answer (score 0):

Do like it:

```
$rows = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
  ->select('e.id AS event_id,ei.id AS image_id, type,title, description,date,path')
  ->from('events e')
  ->join('events_images ei', 'e.id=ei.event_id')
  ->queryAll();
```

Comment: Both solutions works, but the with() is closer to what I want. Tanks!